# Most efficient way to divide Sparse Vector element by an int in a Pyspark Dataframe

Tags: pyspark

I have a pyspark dataframe that contains a column with SparseVectors in each row. I'm looking to divide all the elements of that Sparse vector by length of another column that contains lists.

What would be the most efficient way to do this?

Thank you.

Comment: Convert to RDD and write a map function to loop through the Vector and divide it?

Comment: It seems inefficient seems most of the elements in the sparse vector are zero. Each vector could be 200K